# Is it possible to use the Java ME API or the Android API for a 800x600 touchscreen monitor?

Tags: java, android, java-me

Where I work we have several touchscreens next to each machine, press, laser, etc. I was wondering if it was smart/possible to take advantage of the android or the java me sdk's to perhaps use their advanced pointing gestures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the touch screen currently running on? Most likely they are proprietary software. If they are running on Java or as a second display to a running PC, then you may be able to harness this. In the factory I worked at, all the screens were coded in embedded C - general standard for machine operating touch screens.

You may be out of luck - especially since the screens are not running Android.

Comment: The touchscreens are running remote desktops into a windows machine.

Comment: Well, if you have access you could do that. You have to verify that the screen has multi-touch and that the remote desktop link allows multi-touch if you plan on doing anything fancy like that.

Touch controls and advanced touch techniques in Android are OS level, so re-designing the apps to run in an Android emulator might not be the best solution.

Comment: Referring to my edits on the last comment. You might have to look at Java libraries to do similar, since you don't want to run an emulator of a mobile device - it won't connect to the machines (and if it does, it will have some slow response time for CNC or part building work).

Comment: I should rephrase. I really mean it's a system to track their work and doesn't actually control the machine. Sorry about that. What I mean is that it's a scheduler/time tracker running in java on a client through a remotedesktopconnection